# Looping a batch process until a user presses any key

Tags: loops, batch-file, key

I wish to run a loop inside a batch process, such as a stopwatch or timer that quits the loop and the batch process continues as soon any key is pressed. No break or Cntl-C. There is no batch function for this and it must run in Win64 environment. It seems a simple task to write a short assembly prog.exe but I can't find one that can check the keyboard buffer quickly and return a simpele answer in dos errorlevel without pausing the 'stopwatch' and defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that "short assembly prog.exe" auxiliary program, I called it GetKey.exe and you may download it from this site: [Advanced Batch features via auxiliary .exe programs](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428), look for the program number 3. For example:

```
:loop
   rem Do anything you want here...
   GetKey /N
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto loop
echo The key pressed have this code: %errorlevel%
```

My program is so fast that I even wrote a basic version of Snake animated game in Batch! It is in the same site, below program 6- CursorPos.exe

Antonio